# Having trouble with CSS, how do I make this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this header for my web design class but I'm not very good. I've watched many tutorials but I just don't know what to do. I don't have a problem with the fonts or colors. How do I get it to look like the image below? I can't get the text to line up next to the logo, the search icon to appear on the right side or nav bar to be in the right location.

[what it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boEct.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="beaten path logo" title="beaten path logo">
    <h1 class="the">THE</h1>
    <h1 class="beaten">BEATEN</h1>
    <h1 class="path">PATH</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CHECKOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <img class="search" src="img/search icon.png" alt="search logo" title="search logo">

</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.logo {
    padding: 10px;
}
.the, .path {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
}
.beaten {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(134, 25, 25);
}
nav {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
nav a {
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.search {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: State exactly what is going wrong with your code. "I just can't get anything to go in the right order, correct spacing etc" is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Most important change: `display: flex;` and `width: 100%;` for the `header` to have all the child elements of `header` in one line. And `margin-left: auto` for the `.search` element to move it far right.

And better don't use three `h1` elements, but only one, with a `span` inside it to apply the different color to the second word.

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    padding: 10px;
}
.the, .path {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
}
.beaten {
    color: rgb(134, 25, 25);
}
nav {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
nav a {
    color: rgb(60 61 64);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.search {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="beaten path logo" title="beaten path logo">
    <h1 class="the">THE <span class="beaten">BEATEN</span> PATH</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CHECKOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <img class="search" src="img/search icon.png" alt="search logo" title="search logo">

</header>
```

Comment: I made the changes that @Johannes suggested and for the most part it worked, but now the search icon is stretched out for some reason? And I'm still unsure how to fix the nav bar so it's next to the search icon like in the sample image

Comment: Ah - change that: add `margin-left: auto` to `nav` instead of the search icon to move everything right of it to the right. Concerning the stretched search icon: Add `flex-grow: 0` to it to prevent it from getting wider.

Comment: that did the trick for the nav but the search icon is still stretched. here's what it looks like right now if it helps [link](https://imgur.com/a/56o9L2r). Also thanks @Johannes for all your help

Comment: Ah, it's vertically stretched - I thought horizontally. You didn't include any info about that search icon itself (width, height etc.), but you could try to add `height: auto` to adjust its proportions properly.